# How to efficiently get the count of documents where a specific value is not in a collection with RavenDB?

Tags: indexing, mapreduce, ravendb

In RavenDB, I have a document that looks like this:

```
public class SystemNotification {
    public string Body {get;set;}
    public List<Guid> ReadBy {get;set;}
}
```

How can I create an index to efficiently query for the count of unread notifications for a user ? Or is there a better way to model this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = session.Query<SystemNotification>()
    .Where(x => !x.ReadBy.Any(y => y == yourGuid))
    .Count();
```

Whether there is a better way to model this depends on how many users you will have in your system and a few other things.

As a side note: Don't use Guids for your ids. They are hard to read and have no particular advantage over hilo keys.

Comment: User count will be fairly low (< 200). We are using guids for some ids for infrastructure reasons but we do try to use hilo when we can. Other than readability, are there other obvious disadvantages to Guids ?

Comment: Also, for some reason I assumed that query would be inefficient but I just tried it and it looks good. I guess I should just trust raven to do the Right Thing :)

Comment: Since raven will automatically create an index for you and querying this guy is very fast in such simple situations, yes - you don't need to worry about performance here.

Comment: Guids have no particular disadvantage because they will be converted to strings anyway. So if you deal with things like TransformResults you will have to provide a stirng representation of your Guid, but this won't be a problem at all.